# Borel $\sigma$-algebra and $\sigma$-algebra generated by basis of topology

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, borel-sets

Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topology space, and assume the topology $\tau$ is generated by a basis $\beta$. Set
$$
     \mathcal{F} = \sigma(\tau) \equiv \sigma(\{O: O \in \tau\})
$$
and
$$
     \mathcal{G} = \sigma(\beta) \equiv \sigma(\{B: B \in \beta\})
$$

I wonder if $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{G}$. Since $\beta \subset \tau$, we always have $\mathcal{G} \subseteq \mathcal{F}$. However, I only am be able to show $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{G}$ if $\beta$ is a countable set. Indeed, let $U \in \tau$, then there exists $(B_i)_{i \in I} \subseteq \beta$ such that
$$
     U = \bigcup_{i \in I} B_i \in \sigma(\beta) = \mathcal{G}
$$
Since $\beta$ is countable, the collection $(B_i)_{i \in I}$ must be also countable. Thus, $\tau \subseteq \mathcal{G}$ and therefore $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{G}$. My question is to show $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{G}$ if $\beta$ is uncountable, or if there is a counterexample to this case. Any hints are appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Counterexample: suppose $\tau=\mathcal{P}(X)$ for uncountable $X$, and $\beta$ consists of the singletons.

Comment: @ThomasAnton Ah, I see. In this case $\sigma(\beta)$ only contains countable subset of $X$, whilst $\sigma(\tau)$ can contains uncountable subset, right ?

Comment: It can't only contain countable subsets of $X$, as a sigma algebra is closed under complement. In this case $\sigma(\beta)$ will be the collection of all subsets $A\subseteq X$ such that either $A$ or $X\setminus A$ is countable. $\sigma(\tau)$ on the other hand will be the whole $\mathcal{P}(X)$.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thanks @Mark